# Meteor iOS build error

Tags: ios, meteor

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong? The `meteor run ios-device` command keeps failing on me.

Here's the log: https://gist.github.com/rizkysyazuli/1d20fc709e1613cf0aee

I suspect it's something inside my [mobile-config.js](https://gist.github.com/rizkysyazuli/389664275b8c6d991999), because when i remove it, meteor builds just fine.

And here's my [package](https://gist.github.com/rizkysyazuli/8759cc8c19a5e7be3478) list just in case it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your pre-compiled header file (or 'pch' files) is being modified mid-compilation. I see a lot of "... has been modified since the precompiled header ... please rebuild precompiled header" errors in there. Could the js script be doing something to the pch file?

Comment: i'm not really sure. what do i need to do to check?